# How do I encrypt an already installed Arch System?

Tags: linux, encryption, archlinux, arch

I have a problem with encrypting my Arch Linux Installation. I can only find tutorials on how to encrypt arch during install but not how to encrypt an already installed system.

Some more information:
I currently dualboot with Windows using a GRUB bootloader
Windows and Arch are installed on the same drive.

Comment: Maybe look at this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1197989/108339

Comment: Another one https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265331/26493, so the technically easiest route seems to be backup and reinstall.